# GIMP - While opening psd in gimp it showing unexpected end of file (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gimp

Error is

```
`GIMP Message

Opening '/home/mohsin/Downloads/homepage-3.psd' failed:

Error loading PSD file: Unexpected end of file`
```

I look for this error but I didn't find in Ubuntu.

Comment: The PSD file appears to be damaged. Check file size and see if you can open it with Photoshop.

Comment: Hey @Jos thanks for reply. In Photoshop(wine) same msg I am getting. I tried to open another psd also. getting error while opening.

Comment: @Jos can we use photoshop in Ubuntu without wine ? please help me out in this

Comment: No, my suggestion was to try to open the file on a different computer with Photoshop. "Unexpected end of file" sounds like a download that was canceled before it was finished.

Comment: I don't have another computer. Any solution? can we check online?

Comment: it's opening here! https://www.photopea.com/  means PSD is fine?

Comment: Yes, if it opens, that means there is a bug in GIMP. You could report that to the developers. For now, I would open the file on photopea.com, make a small modification, save the file, and see if it will open in GIMP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80269/discussion-between-mohsin-and-jos).